# Does l2 projection of sequences preserve l1 norm convergence?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Let $\ell^2$ denote the set of square summable sequences with inner product $\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x(i)y(i)$ and $\ell^2$ norm $\|x\|_2=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$. Let $\|x\|_1=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x(i)|$ denote the $\ell_1$ norm. Let $B$ denote a convex closed subset of $\ell_2$, and for $x\in\ell^2$, let

$$\Pi_{B}x=\underset{z\in\ell^2}{\arg\min}\|z-x\|_2$$ denote the Hilbert space projection of $x$ to $B$.

Now, suppose $y\in B$, $\|y\|_1<\infty$, and $\|y_n-y\|_1\to 0$ for a sequence $y_n$ with $\|y_n\|_1<\infty$, for all $n$.

Is it the case that $\|\Pi_{B}y_n\|_1<\infty$?

If so, can we additionally say $\|\Pi_{B}y_n-y\|_1\to 0$? Since $\|y_n-y\|_1\to 0$, we have $\|y_n-y\|_2\to 0$ and thus $\|\Pi_By_n-y\|_2\to 0$. So, my question is whether the projection can make the convergence "worse".

Comment: Let $B$ be the one-dimensional subspace generated by some $x \in l^2 \setminus l^1$ and $y \in l^1$. Anything whose projection onto $B$ doesn't lie in span$(y)$ won't be in $l^1$.

Comment: Thank you! This answers the question as written. In my problem, the set $B$ is the convex cone generated by a collection of vectors in $\ell_1$. Does that change anything?

Comment: In that case wouldn't the entire cone lie in $l^1$?